# Making python for loop faster

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have the following piece of code

```
R_1 = np.zeros(2**K)
R_2 = np.zeros(2**K)
for i in range(2**K): #each possible scenario
    S_1 = [f1(H, P, sigma, s) for s in set1[i]] 
    S_2 = [f2(H, P, sigma, s, set1[i]) for s in set2[i]] 
    R_1[i] = np.sum(np.log(1+np.array(S_1)))
    R_2[i] = np.sum(np.log(1+np.array(S_2)))
```

where K, s are integers, H and P are matrices, set1 and set2 are sets, and f1 and f2 are two functions. The code for f1 is the following (f2 do similar things more or less)

```
def f1(H, P, sigma, i):
    K = H.shape[1]
    N = H.shape[0]
    P_i= P[i]
    h_i = H[:,i][:, np.newaxis]
    P = np.delete(P, i)
    set_minus_i = list(range(K))
    set_minus_i.pop(i)
    S = P_i*h_i.dot(inv(H[:,set_minus_i].dot(np.diag(P)).dot(H[:,set_minus_i]) + sigma**2*np.identity(N))).dot(h_i)
    return S.real
```

The code currently is very slow especially as K grows. Is there a way to make
it faster by using multiprocessing for instance? I'm kind of new to python language. Thank you!

Comment: You can read about multiprocessing in python here :[https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html]

Comment: It's going to grow exponentially regardless because 2**K has exponential growth, and as such your operations grow with that same scale. Even multiprocessing won't help you much for a large K.

Comment: WIthout knowing what the functions do, the only way I see, besides multiprocessing is by vectorizing f1 and/or f2.

Comment: I've seen sequential monte carlo/particle filters used for getting (approximate) answers to this sort of problem.  the maths can get difficult, but it's a way of getting an answer to a known degree of precision

Comment: I edited the post to include the function f1.

Comment: @amdex: Would it be possible to vectorize f1 in this case?

Comment: @TLane: as long as I can use multiprocessing (I have access to 32 processors) that will somehow accelerate things up to a certain point. Is there a way to do that here?